# Cloud Functions for Firebase onWrite() promise always times out

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run a cloud function and change a value on the database, but every time I return a promise with or without 'firebase-admin' module the function times out after 60 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.handleDisconnection = functions.database.ref('/pages/{pageId}/listeners/disconnection')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const eventSnapshot = event.data;
    const isDisconnected = eventSnapshot.val();
    const pageId = event.params.pageId;
    console.log('there is a new disconnection on page ' + pageId + ', isDisconnected: ' + isDisconnected);
    if (eventSnapshot.changed() && isDisconnected) {
      console.log('is disconnected true');
      return admin.database().ref('/pages/'+pageId+'/listeners/disconnection').set({ disconnection: false }).then(() => {
        console.log('Write succeeded!'); // this never triggers
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you see `is disconnected true` in the logs?

Comment: yes, and the other log also shows what i expected

Comment: That looks like it should work to me.  I just did something very similar and got logs and no timeout: `return event.data.adminRef.root.child('bar').set(event.data.val()).then(result => {
        console.log('ok')
    })`

Comment: I switched the return to yours and it also doesn't work :(

Comment: I also tried to update to the latest versions firebase-functions and firebase-admin modules by npm command, i hope it also updates the versions on the server when i deploy

Comment: FWIW: I copied and ran your code and saw `Write succeeded!` in the logs.  In the `set()` statement, don't you want the value to be `false` instead of `{ disconnection: false }` ?  The later adds another `disconnection` segment to the reference path.

Comment: Yes, that was my original intention but it also doesn't work, it looks like there is some kind of problem with my account, because every promise i make from a db triggered cloud function just times out, even the simplest example  suggested above

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (eventSnapshot.changed() && isDisconnected) {
       console.log('is disconnected true');`
       return admin.database.ref('/...')
       .set({ disconnection: false }, err => {
                 if(!err)  // No error 
                       { console.log("Set Updated"); }
       });
```

**set Methods** Has a callback which passes in *err* as object
you can use ***err*** to get the operations status.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the problem was not in the code.

Solved it updating Node.js & npm

Use the "Current" version https://nodejs.org/en/